# Duplicate posts

Tags: posts, query

I'm currently working on a Magazine style website and on the main page I have three different sections where I display the latest news. Slider, latest news and more news.

The problem is I can't figure out how to avoid duplicate posts on each one.

Here is a sample of the query:

```
// build query
query_posts( $this->getQueryParams($type, $esc_category, $this->escapeText($data['number_of_posts'])) );
// loop
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
```

Each section is called as a "Module" so this same code applies for the rest of the queries.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use a static class property to store a rolling list of posts that are used in previous queries. This method allows you to pass data between classes (widgets, modules, plugins, etc...), but will also work for a procedural workflow. Everything on the page that uses your intermediary class will know what posts to exclude.

**Step 1: Create a class that has a static $posts property**

You will need getter and setter methods.

```
class RollingPostsIndex{
    public static $posts = array();

    public function set($new_posts){
        $previous_posts = self::get();
        $posts = array_push($previous_posts, $new_posts);
        return self::$posts = $posts;
    }

    public function get(){
        return self::$posts;
    }
}
```

**Step 2: Create two helper functions to for setting and getting.**

```
function add_rolling_posts($post_ids);
    RollingPostsIndex::set($post_ids);
}

function get_rolling_posts(){
    return RollingPostsIndex::get();
}
```

**Step 3: Track your post ids within your WP_Query instance loops**

```
$post_ids[] = $post->ID;
```

**Step 4: Add the new section post IDs array to the RollingPostsIndex static property**

Use the API function we created earlier.

```
add_rolling_posts($post_ids);
```

**Step 4: Add an argument to your WP_Query instance to exclude previously used post ids.**

```
$args['__post_not_in'] = get_rolling_posts();
```

I've tested this method extensively, and it works really well to keep track of post ids throughout the entire page load.

Hope this helps you out!

Comment: The file where all the queries are is called "Modules.php". From within a page I can call each individual "module" onto the index page.

Comment: @MartinHasan Is each 'module' in a function?

Comment: Exactly. It's all in one file.

Comment: Are you able to edit the modules.php file?

Comment: Yeah, I've tried a couple of thing with no success.

Comment: Did you try to implement the solution I proposed?

Comment: Should I add that to modules.php?

Comment: @MartinHasan Add the class and functions to functions.php and then add the snippets to modules.php

Comment: Yeah, no luck yet...

Comment: @MartinHasan Ping me on my website and we can maybe Skype later.

Answer (score 1):

First, you should be using [`WP_Query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) rather than `query_posts` for these queries. `query_posts` is for altering the main query, but even in that case there are [better methods](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts).

Refer to [WP_Query Post and Page parameters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) to see how to exclude posts from queries:

```
$id_to_exclude = 42;

$args = array(
    'post__not_in' => array( $id_to_exclude )
);
$results = new WP_Query( $args );
```

Comment: The thing is I'm working off a theme, that's why I can't go back and edit the entire code.