# Get most recent posts by category that aren't first overall

Tags: posts, theme-development

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate posts](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60831/duplicate-posts)

I'm trying to create a home page, in which there is a top posts section that displays the three most recent posts (for all categories), and category subsections that display the most recent posts for that category only.

I know how to get that far, but I'm not sure how to make sure there isn't any overlap (I don't want any posts to show up both at the top and in the category section of the page). Is there an efficient way to do this?

Comment: Another: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/50677/how-to-avoid-duplicate-posts-on-front-page  Please use the search feature before posting a question. :)

Comment: Sorry, I searched for a solution before, but didn't find this. Very similar question. Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're going to have a lot of loops and a lot of custom `WP_Query` objects.

To start, create an `$all_posts` variable before you start the main loop on your home page.  You should likely put all this in your `front-page.php` template.

```
<?php
$all_posts = array();
while(have_posts()): the_post();
    $all_posts[] = $post->ID;
    // do stuff with the main loop here
endwhile;
```

On each subsequent loop, use the `$all_posts` variable to exclude posts that already happened.  Say you want to create loops for the categories with the `term_id`'s `1`, `2`, and `3`:

```
<?php
foreach(array(1, 2, 3) as $cat))
{
    $cat_query = new WP_Query(array(
        'cat'   => $cat,
        'post__not_in' => $all_posts,
    ));
    if($cat_query->have_posts()
    {
        while($cat_query->have_posts())
        {
            $cat_query->the_post();
            $all_posts[] = $post->ID;
            // display stuff here
        }
    }
}
```

Just keep appending post IDs to the `$all_posts` variable to make sure subsequent queries don't include posts that were already seen.

Comment: I had forgotten about the 'post__not_in' parameter. This is what I'm looking for. Thanks!